GTM GA4 events out of sync with page_path
We have a SPA site and are having problems with our funnel report in GA4, as it only tracks the first page and not subsequent pages.
We have added a new event, "Quote", that is triggered on either pageView or historyChange, with a parameter for each page, e.g. step1, step2, etc... We can then target the funnel to use the "Quote" event rather than using page_path.
The event has been added as a new dimension to GA4 and the new event is visible in our reports.
The problem we have is that when comparing page_path with the "Quote" event we are seeing a mismatch for customers using the site.
For example:
page_path=/step/1, event=step1 = correct  
page_path=/step/2, event=step2 = correct  
page_path=/step/2, event=step1 = incorrect
page_path=/step/3, event=step1 = incorrect

When testing in GTM using preview we can see the event parameters being set correctly, along with expected page_path. So not sure what customers are doing for this to become out-of-sync in GA.
Could customers be using the back button in their browser, which then causes problems for the historyChange trigger?
